# HelloWorld application using GraalVM not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, graalvm

This is my HelloWorld program as a direct copy from [GraalVM Reference Manual](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/embed-languages/):

```
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;

public class testGraalJS {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Hello Java!");
        try (Context context = Context.create()) {
            context.eval("js", "print('Hello JavaScript!');");
        }
  }
}
```

This is running as supposed using `javac` and `java` at the command prompt (Windows 10):

`Hello Java!`
`Hello JavaScript!`

**The problem comes in Eclipse.**

I've got the following output in the console:

```
Hello Java!
[To redirect Truffle log output to a file use one of the following options:
* '--log.file=<path>' if the option is passed using a guest language launcher.
* '-Dpolyglot.log.file=<path>' if the option is passed using the host Java launcher.
* Configure logging using the polyglot embedding API.]
[engine] WARNING: The polyglot context is using an implementation that does not support runtime compilation.
The guest application code will therefore be executed in interpreted mode only.
Execution only in interpreted mode will strongly impact the guest application performance.
For more information on using GraalVM see https://www.graalvm.org/java/quickstart/.
To disable this warning the '--engine.WarnInterpreterOnly=false' option or use the '-Dpolyglot.engine.WarnInterpreterOnly=false' system property.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A language with id 'js' is not installed. Installed languages are: [].
    at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineException.illegalArgument(PolyglotEngineException.java:131)
    at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineImpl.throwNotInstalled(PolyglotEngineImpl.java:1109)
    at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineImpl.requirePublicLanguage(PolyglotEngineImpl.java:1116)
    at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.requirePublicLanguage(PolyglotContextImpl.java:1491)
    at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.lookupLanguageContext(PolyglotContextImpl.java:1453)
    at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.eval(PolyglotContextImpl.java:1462)
    at com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextDispatch.eval(PolyglotContextDispatch.java:63)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:399)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:425)
    at org.plamen.graal.testGraalJS.main(testGraalJS.java:9)
```

Where it is written: **A language with id 'js' is not installed. Installed languages are: []**

My Build path:
[image: Build path]

If I remove `truffle-api.jar` (as suggested [here](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/956)) I've got the following in the console:

```
Hello Java!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No language and polyglot implementation was found on the classpath. Make sure the truffle-api.jar is on the classpath.
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.noPolyglotImplementationFound(Engine.java:1014)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$PolyglotInvalid.createHostAccess(Engine.java:1004)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$Builder.build(Engine.java:626)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context$Builder.build(Context.java:1851)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.create(Context.java:976)
    at org.plamen.graal.testGraalJS.main(testGraalJS.java:8)
```

My module-info.java:

```
module HelloModule {
    requires org.graalvm.sdk;
    
    exports testGraalJS;
    
}
```

So what is wrong with Eclipse Run Configuration or Build Path?

One more observation:

From [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/embed-languages/#dependency-setup) "you should specify the graal-sdk.jar (which is included in GraalVM) as a provided dependency to your projects."
But I can't find the subject jar file in the latest GraalVM download.
I've downloaded it from [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.sdk/graal-sdk).

EDIT:
Command line:

```
C:\Users\User\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.7.v20230425-1502\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\TestGraalJS\bin;D:\graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.2\graal-sdk-22.3.2.jar"
-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages org.plamen.graal.testGraalJS
--engine.WarnInterpreterOnly=false
```

Comment: Please format your _Console_ output as _Sample Code_ to keep line breaks, not as quote. Please also show your command line (in the launch configuration there is a button _Show Command Line_ for that).

Comment: @andrewJames gu install js was done already, gu list:
 
graalvm                  22.3.2              GraalVM Core                  Supported
                     
js                       22.3.2              Graal.js                      Supported

And the program runs in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Following some clues from [here](https://juejin.cn/post/7024482829316653069), the required `jar` file in Classpath appeared to be `...\languages\js\graaljs.jar`, which in turn asked for `...\languages\icu4j\icu4j.jar`.

So finally, I have 4 jars in the Classpath:

[image: Classpath]

And the command line within Eclipse is:

```
C:\Users\User\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.7.v20230425-1502\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\TestGraalJS\bin;D:\graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.2\languages\js\graaljs.jar;D:\graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.2\languages\icu4j\icu4j.jar;D:\graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.2\graal-sdk-22.3.2.jar;D:\graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.2\lib\truffle\truffle-api.jar"
-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages org.plamen.graal.testGraalJS
```

`CLASSPATH` is not set as a System Variable in Windows. I have `GRAALVM_HOME` as well as `JAVA_HOME`. Maybe that's why everything is so simple when running from the command prompt.